# Why does the second else if statement not execute, but instead executes the first one?

Tags: javascript

I have a problem, when the requirements meet to execute the second else if statement. It executes the first "if" statement? I have no clue why it would not work. It executes `checkleeftijd1();` instead of `checkleeftijd5();`

Thank you in advance!

```
function controle1() {
    let symptoominv1 = document.getElementById("symptoominv1").value;
    let symptoominv2 = document.getElementById("symptoominv2").value;
    let symptoominv3 = document.getElementById("symptoominv3").value;

    if (symptoominv1 == "koorts" || symptoominv1 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv1 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv1 == "diarree" || symptoominv1 == "hoofdpijn" && symptoominv2 == "koorts"|| symptoominv2 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv2 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv2 == "diarree" || symptoominv2 == "hoofdpijn"){
        if (symptoominv3 == "koorts" || symptoominv3 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv3 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv3 == "diarree" || symptoominv3 == "hoofdpijn"){
            checkleeftijd1();
        }else {
            checkleeftijd2();
        }
    }else if (symptoominv1 != "koorts" || symptoominv1 != "keelpijn" || symptoominv1 != "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv1 != "diarree" || symptoominv1 != "hoofdpijn" && symptoominv2 == "koorts"|| symptoominv2 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv2 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv2 == "diarree" || symptoominv2 == "hoofdpijn") {
        if (symptoominv3 == "koorts" || symptoominv3 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv3 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv3 == "diarree" || symptoominv3 == "hoofdpijn"){
            checkleeftijd3();
        }else {
            checkleeftijd4();
        }
    }else if (symptoominv1 == "koorts" || symptoominv1 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv1 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv1 == "diarree" || symptoominv1 == "hoofdpijn" && symptoominv2 != "koorts" || symptoominv2 != "keelpijn" || symptoominv2 != "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv2 != "diarree" || symptoominv2 != "hoofdpijn") {
        if (symptoominv3 == "koorts" || symptoominv3 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv3 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv3 == "diarree" || symptoominv3 == "hoofdpijn") {
            checkleeftijd5();
        }else {
            checkleeftijd4();
        } 
    }    
}
```

Comment: If `symptoominv1` is equal to `"koorts"` then the first `if` part will run. The `||` operator means "or", not "and".

Comment: Also note that a series of `||` comparisons combined with an `&&` comparison needs grouping to be handled correctly in most cases (and *should* have grouping in *all* cases, since the relative precedence of `&&` and `||` is not something most people casually know).

Comment: You should use `if(["koorts","keelpijn","vermoeidheid"].includes(symptoominv1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and comes before or in precedence-
so what you have in the first if is actually (notice the brackets around `(symptoominv1 == "hoofdpijn" && symptoominv2 == "koorts")`:

`(symptoominv1 == "koorts" || symptoominv1 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv1 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv1 == "diarree" || (symptoominv1 == "hoofdpijn" && symptoominv2 == "koorts") || symptoominv2 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv2 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv2 == "diarree" || symptoominv2 == "hoofdpijn")`

so only one of the "ors" needs to be true for the code to enter the if and not continue to the rest of the statements..
use brackets to make sure the order is as you expect:

`if ((symptoominv1 == "koorts" || symptoominv1 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv1 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv1 == "diarree" || symptoominv1 == "hoofdpijn") && (symptoominv2 == "koorts" || symptoominv2 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv2 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv2 == "diarree" || symptoominv2 == "hoofdpijn"))`

and the same goes for the first and second else if:

`else if ((symptoominv1 != "koorts" || symptoominv1 != "keelpijn" || symptoominv1 != "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv1 != "diarree" || symptoominv1 != "hoofdpijn") && (symptoominv2 == "koorts"|| symptoominv2 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv2 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv2 == "diarree" || symptoominv2 == "hoofdpijn"))`

`else if((symptoominv1 == "koorts" || symptoominv1 == "keelpijn" || symptoominv1 == "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv1 == "diarree" || symptoominv1 == "hoofdpijn") && (symptoominv2 != "koorts" || symptoominv2 != "keelpijn" || symptoominv2 != "vermoeidheid" || symptoominv2 != "diarree" || symptoominv2 != "hoofdpijn"))`

Answer (score 0):

First “IF” and its “ELSE IF” have same condition applied, as code compiles line by line so javascript gets conditions satisfied in IF statement that is why it will never even check the else if condition.